# Docx4j: Charset encoding in HTML output

Tags: docx4j

I'm trying to convert docx document to html, but I cant make encoding work well. OutputStream contains xml header with declaration that content is encoded with UTF-8 but instead of language specific signs (like: ąśćźż) I get some garbage. Here is my converter code:

```
public class DocumentProcessor extends DocumentProcessorInterface {
private WordprocessingMLPackage load;
private HTMLSettings htmlSettings;
private Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart filePart;

public DocumentProcessor(Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart filePart) {
    super(filePart);
    this.filePart = filePart;
}

private void prepare() {
    try {
        load = Docx4J.load(filePart.getFile());
        htmlSettings = Docx4J.createHTMLSettings();
        htmlSettings.setImageHandler(new DataUrlImageHandler());
        htmlSettings.setWmlPackage(load);
    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public String getHTML() {
    prepare();
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Logger.info("Converting");
    try {
        Docx4J.toHTML(htmlSettings, outputStream, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Logger.info("Converted");
    return outputStream.toString();
}
```

}

Output looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGUHy.jpg I've already checked database encoding itself.
What have I missed?

Comment: Instead of outputStream.toString(), specify an encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a @JasonPlutext suggested, I should create new string and set encoding to UTF-8.

```
return new String(outputStream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

and that is the answer for my problem.

Comment: Can you please share String() method?

Comment: @SomnathKadam It is just plain java.lang.String. See this construtor: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)